# Issue with image upload php: undefined index

Tags: php, mysql, image, undefined

I am having trouble getting the image upload feature to work on the code below with the following error meesage:

*'An error occurred in script '/database.php' on line 135:
Undefined index: image'*

which is this part:  **'if (is_uploaded_file ($_FILES ['image']['tmp_name'])) {'**

I've done a few php/mysql forms before but this is the first time I've tried to use image uploads. If possible I'm after a form that allows pdfs and jpegs only and limits the upload to 1.5 meg.

The rest of the form works ok, other than that, I have changed the CHMOD to 777 on the uploads folder on the server. Any ideas or suggestions?

```
<?php # index.php
require_once ('./includes/config.inc.php');
$page_title = 'N-Club Battery: Add a Sale';
include ('./includes/header.html');
if (!isset($_SESSION['sp_user_id'])) {
$url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']
. dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
if ((substr($url, -1) == '/') OR (substr($url, -1) == '\\') ) {
$url = substr ($url, 0, -1); // Chop off the slash.
}
$url .= '/login.php'; 
ob_end_clean(); // Delete the buffer.
header("Location: $url"); 
exit(); // Quit the script.
}
$users = $_SESSION['sp_user_id'];
?>
<h1>Heading</h1>
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submitted'])) {// Handle the form.
require_once ('/database.php');
$errors = array(); // Initialize error array.

// Check for a quantity.
if (empty($_POST['npc_quantity'])) {
$errors[] = '<p>• You forgot to enter the Quantity.</p>';
} else {
$quantity = escape_data($_POST['npc_quantity']);
}

// Check for a customer name.
if (empty($_POST['npc_customer_name'])) {
$errors[] = '<p>• You forgot to enter the Customer Name</p>';
} else {
$customers = escape_data($_POST['npc_customer_name']);
}

// Check for an registration number
if (empty($_POST['npc_registration_no'])) {
$errors[] = '• You forgot to enter the Customer Rego Number.';
} else {
$rego = escape_data($_POST['npc_registration_no']);
}

// Check for an SUO number
if (empty($_POST['npc_suo_no'])) {
$errors[] = '• You forgot to enter the SUO Number';
} else {
$suo_no = escape_data($_POST['npc_suo_no']);
}

// Check for an A-Club number
if (empty($_POST['npc_amb_club_no'])) {
$errors[] = '• You forgot to enter the A-Club Number';
} else {
$amb_no = escape_data($_POST['npc_amb_club_no']);
}

// Check for a Repair Order
if (empty($_POST['npc_repair_order'])) {
$errors[] = '• You forgot to enter the Repair Order';
} else {
$rep_no = escape_data($_POST['npc_repair_order']);
}

// Check for a Invoice Number.
if (empty($_POST['npc_invoice_no'])) {
$errors[] = '<p>• You forgot to enter the Invoice Number.</p>';
} else {
$inv = escape_data($_POST['npc_invoice_no']);
}

// Check for a userdate.
if (empty($_POST['npc_entry_userdate'])) {
$errors[] = '<p>• You forgot to enter the entry userdate.</p>';
} else {
$inv_date = escape_data($_POST['npc_entry_userdate']);
}

// Check for an image.
if (is_uploaded_file ($_FILES ['image']['tmp_name'])) {
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES ['image']['tmp_name'], 
"/uploadsfolder/{$_FILES['image']['name']}")) { // Move the file over.

echo '<p>The file has been uploaded!</p>';

} else { // Couldn't move the file over.
echo '<p><font color="red"> The thumbnail image could not be uploaded.</font></p>';
$i = FALSE;
}
$i = $_FILES['image']['name'];
} else {
$i = FALSE;
}

if (empty($errors)) { 

$uid = @mysql_insert_id(); 

// Add the user.
$query = "INSERT INTO npc_sales_list 
(npc_item_id , sp_user_id, npc_battery_n_code, npc_battery_other_code, npc_quantity , 
npc_customer_name, npc_registration_no , npc_suo_no, npc_amb_club_no , npc_repair_order, 
npc_invoice_no, npc_entry_userdate, npc_image_upload, npc_usertype, 
npc_points, npc_bonus_points, npc_entry_date) VALUES
('$uid', '$users', '$_POST[npc_battery_n_code]' , 
'$_POST[npc_battery_other_code]' , '$quantity' , '$customers', 
'$rego' , '$suo_no' , '$amb_no', '$rep_no', '$inv', '$inv_date', 
'$i' , Battery' , '5' , '0' , NOW())";
$result = @mysql_query ($query); // Run the query.

if (mysql_affected_rows() == 1) {

//Finish the page.
echo '<p>The sale with invoice number: <strong>' . $inv . '</strong><br />
is now registered into the system.</p>';
include ('./includes/footer.html'); // Include the HTML footer.
exit();

} else { // If it did not run OK.
echo '<p><font color="red" size="+1">You could not be
registered due to a system error. We apologize for any
inconvenience.</font></p>';
}

} else { // If one of the data tests failed.
echo '<p><font color="red" size="+1">Please check all mandatory fields are complete and try again.
</font></p>';
}

mysql_close(); // Close the database connection.

} // End of the main Submit conditional.
?>                          

<form action="logsales.php" method="post">

<table width="520" border="0" cellspacing="3" cellpadding="2">

<tr>
<td><div align="right">N-Club Battery No<span class="style2">*</span></div></td>
<td>            
<select  name="npc_battery_n_code" id="npc_battery_n_code">
<option value="None" <?php if (isset($_POST['npc_battery_n_code']) && $_POST['npc_battery_n_code'] == 'None') 
{echo 'selected="selected"';} ?>>None</option>
<option value="55D23L" <?php if (isset($_POST['npc_battery_n_code']) && $_POST['npc_battery_n_code'] == '55D23L') 
{echo 'selected="selected"';} ?>>55D23L</option>
<option value="55D23R" <?php if (isset($_POST['npc_battery_n_code']) && $_POST['npc_battery_n_code'] == '55D23R') 
{echo 'selected="selected"';} ?>>55D23R</option>                                
<option value="75D23R" <?php if (isset($_POST['npc_battery_n_code']) && $_POST['npc_battery_n_code'] == '75D23R') 
{echo 'selected="selected"';} ?>>75D23R</option>
</select>
</td>
</tr>  

<tr>
<td width="184"><div align="right">Other Battery No<span class="style2">*</span></div></td>
<td width="323">
<select  name="npc_battery_other_code" id="npc_battery_other_code">
<option value="None"  <?php if (isset($_POST['npc_battery_other_code']) && $_POST['npc_battery_other_code'] == 'None') 
{echo 'selected="selected"';} ?>>None</option>
<option value="3"  <?php if (isset($_POST['npc_battery_other_code']) && $_POST['npc_battery_other_code'] == '3') 
{echo 'selected="selected"';} ?>>3</option>
<option value="26" <?php if (isset($_POST['npc_battery_other_code']) && $_POST['npc_battery_other_code'] == '26') 
{echo 'selected="selected"';} ?>>26</option>                                                               
<option value="29" <?php if (isset($_POST['npc_battery_other_code']) && $_POST['npc_battery_other_code'] == '29') 
{echo 'selected="selected"';} ?>>29</option>
<option value="30" <?php if (isset($_POST['npc_battery_other_code']) && $_POST['npc_battery_other_code'] == '30') 
{echo 'selected="selected"';} ?>>30</option>
</select></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><div align="right">Quantity <span class="style2">*</span></div></td>
<td><input type="text" name="npc_quantity" size="10" maxlength="10" 
value="<?php if (isset($_POST['npc_quantity'])) echo $_POST['npc_quantity']; ?>" /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><div align="right">Customer Name <span class="style2">*</span></div></td>
<td><input type="text" name="npc_customer_name" size="30" maxlength="30" 
value="<?php if (isset($_POST['npc_customer_name'])) echo $_POST['npc_customer_name']; ?>" /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><div align="right">Customer Rego number <span class="style2">*</span></div></td>
<td><input type="text" name="npc_registration_no" size="10" maxlength="7" 
value="<?php if (isset($_POST['npc_registration_no'])) echo $_POST['npc_registration_no']; ?>" /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><div align="right">SUO Number <span class="style2">*</span></div></td>
<td><input type="text" name="npc_suo_no" size="20" maxlength="30" 
value="<?php if (isset($_POST['npc_suo_no'])) echo $_POST['npc_suo_no']; ?>" /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><div align="right">A-Club ID <span class="style2">*</span></div></td>
<td><input type="text" name="npc_amb_club_no" size="20" maxlength="30" 
value="<?php if (isset($_POST['npc_amb_club_no'])) echo $_POST['npc_amb_club_no']; ?>" /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><div align="right">Repair Order<span class="style2">*</span></div></td>
<td><input type="text" name="npc_repair_order" size="20" maxlength="30" 
value="<?php if (isset($_POST['npc_repair_order'])) echo $_POST['npc_repair_order']; ?>" /></td>
</tr>


<tr>
<td><div align="right">Invoice Number <span class="style2">*</span></div></td>
<td><input type="text" name="npc_invoice_no" size="20" maxlength="30" 
value="<?php if (isset($_POST['npc_invoice_no'])) echo $_POST['npc_invoice_no']; ?>" /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><div align="right">Date of Invoice <span class="style2">*</span></div></td>
<td><input type="text" name="npc_entry_userdate" size="20" maxlength="10" 
value="<?php if (isset($_POST['npc_entry_userdate'])) echo $_POST['npc_entry_userdate']; ?>" /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td></td>
<td>
<span class="sml_italics">MM-DD-YYYY </span></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><div align="right">Invoice copy<span class="style2">*</span></div></td>
<td> 
<input type="file" name="image"  size="30" maxlength="60" /> <br />
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td></td>
<td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" /></p><input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="TRUE" />
&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</table>

</form>

<p>footer</p>

<?php
include ('./includes/footer.html');
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `<form>` does not have an `enctype` attribute.

```
<form action="logsales.php" method="post">
```

It needs to be:

```
<form action="logsales.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Without it, your browser doesn't know how to send the file to your server, so without the `enctype`, it won't work. More information available at [W3](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.3).

Comment: I tried this but I got both the 'The file is uploaded!'and the 'You could not be registered due to a system error. We apologize for any inconvenience.' messages. It did upload the image but not the rest of the form data...

Comment: I've just realized that there was a quotation mark missing before Battery, so this now works. thanks for that nickb

Answer (score 1):

Also Add another if condition above your `if (is_uploaded_file ($_FILES ['image']['tmp_name']))` as below:

```
if (isset($_FILES['image']) && $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'] != ''){
  if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])){  
  ................your logic here.............
  }
}
```