# Image upload file type validation using php - pdf and jpeg

Tags: php, mysql, image, file-upload

I have the following script for part of a form which allows a file upload, full script is here: [Issue with image upload php: undefined index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11750866/issue-with-image-upload-php-undefined-index). It works ok in that it stops the script if there is no file selected and uploads when the form is fully populated (for logged in users only)

What I am trying to do with no luck so far, however is confine the upload type to pdf and jpeg only.

Any suggestions welcome

```
    <?php         
    if (is_uploaded_file ($_FILES ['image']['tmp_name'])) {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES ['image']['tmp_name'], 
    "uploads/{$_FILES['image']['name']}")) { // Move the file over.
    echo '<p>The file has been uploaded!</p>';
    } else { // Couldn't move the file over.
    echo '<p><font color="red"> The thumbnail image could not be uploaded.</font></p>';
    $i = FALSE;
    }
    $i = $_FILES['image']['name'];
    } else {
    $i = FALSE;
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 3):

You should read the manual [$_FILE type](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php)  It would be something like:

```
if ($_FILES['file']['type'] == 'image/jpeg')  && ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/pdf")
```

Comment: Do you know how to display the signature in PDF format using this? my iframe is now showing the PDF signature, it is saving it but not showing it.

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick for you...

```
    <?php
    if(isset($_FILES['image'])&&(!empty($_FILES['image']))){  
    if (($_FILES['image']['type']== "image/jpeg")||($_FILES['image']['type'] == "application/pdf")){
$filename =$_FILES['image']['name'];
    $copy = copy($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], "uploads/".$filename);
    if($copy){
    echo '<p>The file has been uploaded!</p>';
    }else{
    echo 'File is not a jpeg or pdf';
    }
    }else{
    echo '<p><font color="red"> The thumbnail image could not be uploaded.</font></p>';
    }
    }else{
    echo 'no image is selected';
    } 
    ?>
```

Comment: This script managed to get the pdf and jpeg verified and uploaded the script to the right folder, but it renamed the file name to 1. Is there any way of preserving the file name?

Comment: Oh sorry i didn't notice that. I have edited the answer.. now its okay check it.

Comment: did you getting same result..??

Comment: Yes, everything uploaded ok but the filename was called 1

Comment: I have tested it now, it works perfect for me. place the code you use here i will check if there is any other problem